# Rendering or updating react element on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs

In my React app all of my components can update themselves through the browser, however a module I'm using called `jenkins-api` only works when I call it server side. I can get the data and pass it into my template like this:

```
require("babel-core/register")({presets: ['es2015', 'react']});
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Component = require('../src/javascripts/components/Areachart');
var jenkinsapi = require('jenkins-api');
var jenkins = jenkinsapi.init('https://username:password@my.jenkins.server:8080', {strictSSL: false});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  jenkins.all_jobs(function(err,jenkins-res){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    res.render('index', { title: 'My App', data: JSON.stringify(jenkins-res) });
  })
});
```

But I'm having trouble making this data available to my react component, ideally I would like to be able to do something like this

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  jenkins.all_jobs(function(err,jenkins-res){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    res.render('index', { title: 'My App', data: Component.setState({prop1: jenkins-res.prop1, prop2: jenkins-res.prop2 });
```

I have even tried rendering the entire React component:

```
res.render('index', { title: 'My App', data: ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Component), document.getElementById('main'))});
```

But this does not work because `document` doesn't exist. I would like to use `.setState` or something similar to update the state of my component when the data has been retrieved by the server - is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I made this work by having my React components send requests to my server once they've mounted, when the request is received my express app will send back the relevant data